# Opengl: How to map a buffer CORRECTLY?

Tags: c++, dictionary, opengl, buffer

I'm new to stack overflow. I have the following problem: I want to have a rotating triangle in my window. 
Now, I have already managed to have my code running and I had a rotating triangle. However, I wanted to rewrite the code for learning purposes, adding the two following major things:

1. Updating the buffer object later on with memcpy
2. Having an array-of-stuctures (AoS) instead of a structure-of-arrays (SoA)

I'm referring hereby to the "OpenGL Superbible" book.
I'll provide you some code snippets:

```
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    static const vertex vertices[] = {
        { 0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0 ,
          1.0,   0.0,  0.0, 1.0},

        { -0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0,
           0.0,   1.0,  0.0, 1.0 },

        { 0.25,  0.25, 0.5, 1.0,
          0.0,   0.0,  1.0, 1.0 }
    };
    glCreateBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glNamedBufferStorage(buffer, sizeof(vertices), NULL, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

    void * ptr = glMapNamedBuffer(buffer, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
    memcpy(ptr, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    glUnmapNamedBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

    glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, buffer, 0, sizeof(vmath::vec4));
    // Positions
    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, 0, 0);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, offsetof(vertex, x));
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, 0);

    // Color
    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, 1, 0);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, offsetof(vertex, r));
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, 1);

    glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, buffer, 0, sizeof(vertex));
```

I set up the vertex struct as follows:

```
struct vertex {
    // Position
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float w;

    // Color
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
    float a;
};
```

The first time, I had the color hard-coded in my vertex shader. And I had the position data in a data-array. I set the data directly by calling 'glNamedBufferStorage' instead of (as it is now the case) inserting NULL. Back then, it worked. But as I changed the two things, it stopped working. I know by shure that both of these major steps include some errors.

Here I'll provide you with the vertex shader. the mvp matrix works, by the way, so that's not the problem.

```
        #version 420 core
        layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;                                    
        layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;                                    
        out vec4 vs_color;                                                          
        uniform mat4 mvp;                                                          
        void main(void)                                                            
        {                                                                          

            gl_Position =   mvp * position;                                        
            vs_color = color;                                                      
        }
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your current code already handle the rotation correctly? Here I don't see any time code.

Comment: I have the time in my render function. But as I said, that was not the problem part. It handles it correctly, with correct matrices.

Comment: @Attersson all I had to do was basically to learn how to debug OpenGL. After that was done, all was clear... I didn't know that was even possible at that point. I watched the playlist "OpenGL" by  the Youtuber "TheCherno". It's much more comprehensible for a 3D-Graphics beginner than "The OpenGL Superbible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in the code:

`glUnmapNamedBuffer` takes the buffer handle as parameter, not a GLenum. Change `glUnmapNamedBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);` to `glUnmapNamedBuffer(buffer);`. (And you should check the return value, it returns false when there is a problem).

The stride for `glVertexArrayVertexBuffer` is wrong. Each vertex starts 8 floats after the previous one (or `sizeof(vertex)`). Change

```
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, buffer, 0, sizeof(vmath::vec4));
```

to

```
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, buffer, 0, sizeof(vertex));
```

Comment: Thanks
I indeed followed your second advice. Your first one kind  of helped me too. I then used glMapBuffer and passed the binding point to it. But, furthermore I had to add glBindVertexArray. Further, I maybe changed the order of some functions I called, but I dont know if that was necessary.